# Iterating two lists for filtering

Tags: python, list, filter

I have 2 lists and I am trying to filter the second list based on a condition in the first list.

```
list1 = [ {'type': 'A', 'name': '1'},{'type': 'B', 'name': '2'},{'type': 'A', 'name': '3'}]
list2 = [100, 200, 300]

filtered_list1 = list(filter(lambda x: (x['type'] == 'A'), list1))
filtered_list2 = list(filter(lambda x: ??????????????????, list2))

# expected output
# filtered_list1 = [ {'type': 'A', 'name': '1'},{'type': 'A', 'name': '3'}]
# filtered_list2 = [100, 300]
```

I need to filter elements in list2 based on a condition in list1. How can I iterate over two lists? Or is it possible to use an index with filter/lambda?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `zip` to visit the corresponding list elements in pairs. You can then unpack the zipped pairs inside a conditional list comprehension, and you're done:

```
filtered_list2 = [ y for (x, y) in zip(list1, list2) if x["type"] == "A" ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `zip` to iterate over two lists at the same time

```
>>> list1 = [ {'type': 'A', 'name': '1'},{'type': 'B', 'name': '2'},{'type': 'A', 'name': '3'}]
>>> list2 = [100, 200, 300]
>>>
>>> fil1, fil2 = zip(*((e1, e2) for e1, e2 in zip(list1, list2) if e1['type']=='A'))
>>> 
>>> list(fil1)
[{'type': 'A', 'name': '1'}, {'type': 'A', 'name': '3'}]
>>> list(fil2)
[100, 300]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here'e one way using a list comprehension with `enumerate`, and keeping values from both lists based on the condition. You can further `zip` the result and keep both filtered lists separately, this way *a single list comprehension suffices*:

```
out = ((list1[i], list2[i]) for i, d in enumerate(list1) if d['type'] == 'A')
filtered_list1, filtered_list2 = list(zip(*out))

print(filtered_list1)
# ({'type': 'A', 'name': '1'}, {'type': 'A', 'name': '3'})

print(filtered_list2)
# (100, 300)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a list comperhention:

```
list1 = [ {'type': 'A', 'name': '1'},{'type': 'B', 'name': '2'},{'type': 'A', 'name': '3'}]
list2 = [100, 200, 300]

filtered_list1 = list(filter(lambda x: (x['type'] == 'A'), list1))
filtered_list2 = list(filter(lambda x: x in [int(l.get('name'))*100 for l in 
filtered_list1], list2))
```